# In SqlAlchemy ORM with MySql, I have a many-to-many relationship between assoc and airframe tables and want 1st unique engine_id result

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy

```py
airframe= Base.classes['airframe']
assoc= Base.classes['airframe_association']
stmt = select(assoc.engine_id,airframe.airframe_model).join(airframe, assoc.airframe_id == airframe.id).where(assoc.engine_id.in_(merged_df['engine_id']),airframe.CODE.isnot(None))
with Session(engine_db) as session:
    result = session.execute(stmt)
    for row in result:
        print(row.engine_id,row.airframe_model)
```

```
34 ERJ-190
92 A321-200
94 A319-100
94 A320-200
112 A321-200
114 A320-200
114 A321-200
129 A340-300
133 737-700
133 737-800
134 737-700
134 737-800
149 737-700
149 737-800
151 737-700
151 737-800
161 737-700
161 737-800
163 737-700
163 737-800
293 A330-200
293 A330-300
316 A319-100
317 A320-200
319 A319-100
320 A321-200
320 A321-100
321 A321-200
```